# Removing @replies from twitter so they are not displayed on my website

Tags: twitter

Ive been trying to exclude twitter @replies from my website using bits of code I googled but still unfortunately lost.

its located here www.johnnyharu.com

Can anyone help?

Another newbie

Comment: Could you post the code you tried to use?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions and run any incoming messages through a filter, such as sed.

Your regular expressions could be something like (correct me if I'm wrong regex gurus):

```
@[^ \t\n]+
```

If you wanted to use sed, this command would strip them for you:

```
s/@[^ \t\n]+//g
```